# record = Member.find_by_user(params[:member][:user])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, find

I found a sample code like the title of this post and have a question.
Why is this written like `params[:member][:user]`?

I got advice from my friend and he explained that `[:member]` means table name and `[:user]` means column name included in the table of `member`.
But I don't get it because table is always plural and it is obvious that he or she are trying to search in table `members` as showed `Member.find`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is written as `params[:member][:user]` because params is a nested hash, such as this:

```
params = {"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"uAbvJ/LE1f8eDcANe+TVip5nsWfP/xJxxoGmsQyKFnU=",
  "access_token"=>"",
  "member"=> {"name"=>"foobar",
      "email"=>"foo@bar.com",
      "user"=>"jimmy",
      "session"=>"2013-01-17 13:15:00 UTC"},
  "commit"=>"Submit",
  "locale"=>"es"}
```

This means to get to the value of the user inside of `member`, you would need to write something like `params[:member][:user]`. This is typical behavior of forms submitted by Rails, as the model data will be in it's own hash as `member` is in this example.